# Iphone, Android - Weird behaviour jq-mobile - own img´s as icons

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, image-processing

Heyo i´m having strange troubles with my jquery-mobile-page build with jqm

i´d like to set custom images as button-icons having my own `mobile.css` doing so :

```
#foo1 .ui-icon-forward { height: 38px;width:38px;padding:15px;overflow:hidden; background:url(../images/m/btns.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#foo1 .ui-icon-alert { height: 38px;width:38px;padding:15px;overflow:hidden; background:url(../images/m/btns.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#foo1 .ui-icon-delete { height: 38px;width:38px;padding:15px;overflow:hidden; background:url(../images/m/btns.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#foo1 .ui-icon-home { height: 38px;width:38px;padding:15px;overflow:hidden; background:url(../images/m/btns.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#foo1 .ui-icon-search { height: 38px;width:38px;padding:15px; overflow:hidden;background:url(../images/m/btns.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

here´s the image(i know they all point to the first in the css above):

[image]

and her´s the html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>immobile</title>
        <meta name = "viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerymobile.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper" data-role="page">
    <div id="hpwrap">
               <div data-role="header"  data-theme="d"  data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-corners="false" data-id="headerm" id="foo1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"  data-role="button"  data-icon="home" data-transition="fade"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-role="button"  data-icon="search" data-transition="fade"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"  data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"  data-ajax="false" data-icon="delete" id="nonMobile" rel="      external" data-theme="d"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <p style="color:white;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">
        what the *'$§%' is going on with the images and why ?
    </p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in **every** modern desktop browser this look fine

like [image]

but on an Iphone or android phone it looks more like :

[image]

so this is weird, it has nothing to do about using sprites or not, i even tryed different img-file-types (jpeg,gif,png)
, tryed to add z-indiziees played around with paddings and stuff, tryed to remove effects like text-shadow and ie-fixes for .ui-btn-stuff in jqm.css and other trys for 2 days now and i´m stuck but really want to use my icons :) 
so in the scenario above nothing changed in the jqm-source-files and all my trys didnt help a bit

maybe anyone encountered this problem before or has any hint or row in jqm.css?
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed that using my own data-icon

like

```
data-icon="myOwnIcon"
```

and css like

```
.ui-icon-myOwnIcon {
   background: url(../images/m/2map.png) no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
}
```

still don´t know why but this way the images are rendered correctly